# Regular expression to detect and combine repeated tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'm using regular expressions to extract data from a page controlled by another group in my organization. The basic structure follows the same pattern:

```
<td><strong>Text I'm looking for</strong>...<a href="Link I'm also looking for"></a></td>
```

I am able to successfully grab the desired data with

```
<td><strong>(?<title>.*?)</strong>(.*?)<a href="(?<link>.*?)">(.*?)</a></td>
```

However I occasionally run into a group that looks like

```
<td><strong>Text I'm </strong><strong>looking for</strong>...<a href="Link I'm also looking for"></a></td>
```

Is there a regular expression to handle this? It would preferably combine the two blocks automatically but I could combine them manually if necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *regular expressions* to parse HTML is difficult and not safe. There is a .NET library that can help you with this: `Html Agility Pack` *( http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)*
(it supports `XPATH` and `XSLT`)

Comment: Obligatory link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could post-process the first "text I'm looking for" to replace the string `"</strong><strong>"` with the empty string.

The System.String type has a Replace method that would do nicely.